# PHP Complex regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm typing this on an iPhone so it'll be hard for me to format code etc.

Basically, I have a text file with the contents similar to below:

```
Mercedes Benz 4726498 on April 23rd 2015 03:02:14 am (1847284839)
Vauxhall Astra 3819482 on April 25th 2015 01:26:34 pm (382838484)
Vauxhall Astra Estate 4728482 (22) on June 22nd 2015 02:48:42 pm (382848388)
```

Basically, it's a series of one of more words, a 7 digit number, then a chance of a number in between brackets, a date string and a number in brackets at the end

Every line will have the series of words, 7 digit number, date string and number at the end

The number in brackets such as on the third line is on some lines but not all

Basically, I want to write a regular expression in PHP to extract all that information except the date string

I've tried absolutely all sorts, trial and error for ages and just can't get to the solution!

If anyone can give me a helping hand I'd be very grateful! :-)

Edited to add commented best try:
it is something like this:

```
preg_match('/(^[a-zA-Z\'-]+\s[a-zA-Z\'-]+) ([0-9]+) (([0-9]+))(\s(([0-9]{2}?)))?/', $line, $matches);
```

Thanks guys!
Mark

Comment: Please post your best attempt, even if it doesn't work. The solution is rather simple, and it should be easy to explain where you are going wrong.

Comment: Try a live regex editor ( http://www.phpliveregex.com ) to fiddle around!

Comment: @Amadan I'm currently off my computer at the minute, but it is something like this: preg_match('/(^[a-zA-Z\'-_]+\s[a-zA-Z\'-_]+) ([0-9]+) \(([0-9]+)\)(\s\(([0-9]{2}?)\))?/', $line, $matches); ----- I just can't seem to make it optionally grab the number in brackets. I'm clearly not a regex expert! My code also only takes two words, not multiple. So if 3 words are starting the line, it won't match :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to work:

`([A-Za-z ]*) ([0-9]{7}) (?:\(([0-9]{2})\) )?on ([A-Za-z0-9: ]*) \(([0-9]*)\)`

When applied to the example inputs, we get the following arrays:

```
array(6
    0   =>  Mercedes Benz 4726498 on April 23rd 2015 03:02:14 am (1847284839)
    1   =>  Mercedes Benz
    2   =>  4726498
    3   =>  
    4   =>  April 23rd 2015 03:02:14 am
    5   =>  1847284839
)

array(6
    0   =>  Vauxhall Astra Estate 4728482 (22) on June 22nd 2015 02:48:42 pm (382848388)
    1   =>  Vauxhall Astra Estate
    2   =>  4728482
    3   =>  22
    4   =>  June 22nd 2015 02:48:42 pm
    5   =>  382848388
)
```

Try it out at http://www.phpliveregex.com !

Comment: That looks pretty damn spot on, I shall give it a try tomorrow when I am back at my computer and mark it as the right answer!  Cheers man

Comment: Good good. Do still post your solution attempt in the original post!

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating. Firstly, in general it won't be necessary to be that specific about which characters can come in as words. Secondly, if you don't know how many words there will be, don't try to match them as separate words.

```
(\D+)\s+(\d+)\s+(?:\((\d+)\))?.*\((\d+)\)
```

should be enough:

- Some non-digits (capture as group 1)
- some spaces
- some digits (capture as group 2)
- some spaces
- possibly parentheses, some digits inside (capture them as group 3)
- stuff
- parentheses, some digits inside (capture them as group 4)

If it is possible there might be digits in the car name, then you might need to be a bit more precise in defining the next thing (the number):

```
(.+)\s+(\d{7})\s+(?:\((\d+)\))?.*\((\d+)\)
```